# Excel: Formula to choose today if another value is before today?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I was trying to figure out how to set a cell date value based on the dates from another column.  I wanted to be able to set today's date if the value in the referenced cell is before today, so I was using a formula along the lines of the following:

```
=IF((TODAY()-D2),D2,TODAY())
```

But that doesn't seem to be working.  How can I test if a date is before today, and set today's date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
=IF(D2<TODAY(),TODAY(),D2)
```

Remember to set the output collum to use Date type numbers.

Comment: Don't forget to convert `;` to `,` when writing for english Excel users :)

Answer (score 2):

So you want the later date out of D2 and today? Try `MAX`

`=MAX(D2,TODAY())`

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I just realized I forgot to test if it was negative, and I had some things backwards.

```
=IF((TODAY()-D2)<0,TODAY(),D2)
```